# AJAX uploading files not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I want to upload text files on browser using ajax but I'm not getting how to do that. The file is not uploaded and var_dump($files) echoes array(0).

HTML:

```
<form id="uploadsql" action="upload.js" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input id="uploadFile" type="text" disabled="disabled" placeholder="Choose File" />
    <div  class="fileUpload btn btn-primary">
        <span>Upload</span>
        <input id="uploadBtn" name="file" type="file" class="upload"required />
    </div>

    <div class="fileUpload btn btn-primary">
        <span>Submit</span>
    <input type = "submit" id="uploadBtn" class="upload" /></div>

    </form>
    <h4 id='loading' >Loading...</h4>
    <div id="message"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">  
            document.getElementById("uploadBtn").onchange = function () {  
                document.getElementById("uploadFile").value = this.value;
            };
    </script>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
$("#uploadsql").on('submit',(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
$("#message").empty();
$('#loading').show();
$.ajax({
url: "upload.php", // Url to which the request is send
type: "POST",             // Type of request to be send, called as method
cache: false,             // To unable request pages to be cached
success: function(data)   // A function to be called if request succeeds
{
$('#loading').hide();
$("#message").html(data);
}
});
}));


});
```

PHP:

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);
header('content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
header("access-control-allow-origin: *");

include 'connect.php';


if(isset($_FILES["uploadBtn"]["type"]))
{
echo 'yes';

} else {
    $files = $_FILES;
    var_dump ($files);
}



?>
```

What am I doing wrong here?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sending multipart/formdata with jQuery.ajax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392344/sending-multipart-formdata-with-jquery-ajax)

Comment: Thanks @apokryfos it helped!

Answer (score 0):

well by looking at your ajax call, you are not including the "data" attrribute  to the ajax  object. But i recommend you look at this answer [jQuery AJAX file upload PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23980733/jquery-ajax-file-upload-php)